# Creating a tag manager similar to google tag manager

Tags: javascript, tags

I wanted to create my own tag manager (something like google tag manager) from scratch. Can you please suggest any documents I can go through, or any idea how to get started ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to create your own tag manager or analytics tool. There are good two opensource analytics tools which are [Piwik](https://github.com/piwik/piwik) and [analytics.js](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics.js)

So you can examine opensource analytics platforms and build your own required analytics tool.